# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, json

I'm getting the following error when trying to populate my list view with JSON data:

```
10-01 11:50:34.678    2782-2797/? I/System.out﹕ Returned Json object {"match_name":"EG vs EHOME","match_time":"2015-10-15 09:00:00"}
10-01 11:50:34.678    2782-2782/? I/System.out﹕ Resulted Value: {"match_name":"EG vs EHOME","match_time":"2015-10-15 09:00:00"}
10-01 11:50:34.679    2782-2782/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-01 11:50:34.679    2782-2782/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.eduard.games, PID: 2782
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
```

on the following line of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
```

My method adding the json data to the listview

```
List<getMatch> returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

    List<getMatch> jsonObject = new ArrayList<getMatch>();

    JSONObject resultObject = null;

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    getMatch newItemObject = null;


    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

        JSONObject jsonChildNode;

        try {

            jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String match_name = jsonChildNode.getString("match_name");

            String match_time = jsonChildNode.getString("match_time");


            newItemObject = new getMatch(match_name, match_time);

            jsonObject.add(newItemObject);

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

my json output:

```
[{"match_name":"Secret vs EG","match_time":"2015-09-30 02:06:30"},     {"match_name":"LGD vs EHOME","match_time":"2015-10-08 13:10:00"},   {"match_name":"EG vs EHOME","match_time":"2015-10-15 09:00:00"}]
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You never assigned a value to `jsonArray`

Comment: The null initialization and the attempt to call a method on it are literally 2 lines apart. As an extra bonus, the error log tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: everyone in above comment gave proper explanation...this look duplicate of what is NPE?...plus looking at your result json...i doubt you even need JSONArray

Comment: Thanks for the help @HarishVed. I got it working... What a stupid mistake~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as simple 
here you

```
JSONArray jsonArray = null;

getMatch newItemObject = null;


for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
```

are creating null json array and consuming its method in for loop. Instiate the JsonArray first.

Answer (score -1):

dont make null JSONarray. initialized it first